# Border radius on image not working (Android)

Tags: css, nativescript

I'm trying to get an image with rounded corners so that it turns into a circle image so to speak. I'm using vue-nativescript.

html:

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="space-around">
        <StackLayout class="stack-layout-logo">
            <Image
                src="~/assets/images/passer.png"
                stretch="aspectFit"
                class="image-logo"
            ></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="stack-layout-logo">
            <Image
                src="~/assets/images/passer.png"
                stretch="aspectFill"
                class="image-logo"
            ></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="stack-layout-logo">
            <Image src="~/assets/images/passer.png" stretch="none" class="image-logo"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

css:

```
.stack-layout-logo {
    background-color: lime;
    height: 25%;
}

.image-logo {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried different stretches but none seem to do what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `stretch = "aspectFit"` with `stretch = "aspectFill"` or `stretch = "none"`. I have experienced the same thing before

Answer (score 0):

Simple bordrRadius won't work on Android, you have to provide border radius of all 4 corners i.e topRight, topLeft, bottomRight and bottomLeft

```
const width = 20 // whatever is width of your image
const imgStyle = {
  borderRadius: width / 2,
  borderBottomLeftRadius: width / 2,
  borderBottomRightRadius: width / 2,
  borderTopRightRadius: width / 2,
  borderTopLeftRadius: width / 2
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#borderradius), you should use like that:

```
.image-logo {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 20;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you want to round a specific corner, you can try this:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#borderbottomleftradius

Nice pic btw.

Comment: Hello! I wonder if ReactNative and NativeScript are so much alike? I did try your change with no avail :(

Comment: lol, my SO tagged your question as a react-native one. I'm sorry mate. Should i remove it?

Comment: Nah leave it! It might *just* help a react dude down the line! I did figure out how to fix this, will be posting an answer myself soon :P